# style a navigation link when a particular div is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have JQuery working to show a particular div when a certain link is clicked. 
I have managed to apply the effect I'm after with the main navigation bar through id'ing the `body` tag and using css to style when the id is found.

However, i'd like to apply the same effect to the sub navigation when a certain div is present.

How the main navigation is styled:

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li id="nav-home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li id="nav-showreel"><a href="showreel.html">Showreel</a></li>
<li id="nav-portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body#home li#nav-home, 
body#portfolio li#nav-portfolio
{
background: url("Images/Nav_Underline.png") no-repeat;
background-position: center bottom;
color: white;
}
```

(Other links havent been added to styling as those pages are still in development)

How the sub navigation is structured:

```
<nav id="portfolioNav">
<ul>
<li id="portfolio-compositing"><a id="compositingWork" href="#">Compositing</a></li>
<li id="portfolio-animation"><a id="animationWork" href="#">Animation</a></li>
<li id="portfolio-motionGfx"><a id="GFXWork" href="#">Motion Graphics</a></li>
<li id="portfolio-3D"><a id="3DWork" href="#">3D</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see, its similar format to the main navigation, however i've tried the same approach and it doesn't work :(

The Javascript that switches the divs on the navigation click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#3DWork').click(function(){

    $('#portfolioWork').load('portfolioContent.html #Portfolio3D');
});

$('#GFXWork').click(function(){

    $('#portfolioWork').load('portfolioContent.html #motionGraphics');
});

$('#compositingWork').click(function(){

    $('#portfolioWork').load('portfolioContent.html #PortfolioCompositing');
});
$('#animationWork').click(function(){

    $('#portfolioWork').load('portfolioContent.html #PortfolioAnimation');
});

});
</script>
```

JSFiddle for full HTML & CSS : [JSFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/ByASH/)

The effect I'm After:[image: The effect I'm After:]

Comment: Do you mean highlight it when the window shows it or when it is present on the page?

Comment: When its present within the page. 
When either "Compositing", "Animation", "Motion Graphics" or "3D" are clicked, the section below with all the thumbnails switches to a div thats stored within another html file (that all works fine)
I was just wondering how I might go about highlighting the correct link when a particular div below is displayed

Comment: The jsFiddle doesn't work because the images are being blocked for me. Any way you can post the actual site url?

Comment: http://www.mattmeadows.info/JessWebsite/portfolio.html

Comment: `if ($("div").is(:visible)){}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your script like this:

```
$('#compositingWork').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#portfolioWork').load('portfolioContent.html #PortfolioCompositing');
    });
```

and add this to css:

```
.active
{
background: url("Images/Nav_Underline.png") repeat-x;
background-position: center bottom;
}
```

upd. but the easier way is to combine similar strings:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind link id and id for load()
    var loadDiv = {
        '3DWork': 'Portfolio3D',
        'GFXWork': 'motionGraphics',
        'compositingWork': 'PortfolioCompositing',
        'animationWork': 'PortfolioAnimation'
    };
    var links = $('#3DWork, #GFXWork, #compositingWork, #animationWork');
    links.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // remove effect from all links
        links.parent('li').removeClass('active');
        // and add to clicked one
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        // load you contant using array of ids
        $('#portfolioWork').load('portfolioContent.html #'+loadDiv[this.id]);
    });
});
```

also I don't think you need an image for this effect. Why not using border-botom style with width and color you need?

check this example http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/sJNMR/
(I also added "[prevent default](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)" action for your need)

Comment: The link itself already has that on hover, i was looking to style it exactly the same upon being clicked active i think?

Comment: edited my code (though I have better and more elegant solution for you but I need time to prepare it)

Comment: No such luck with your suggestion i'm afraid

Comment: I added more relevant solution

Comment: That works great, however its applied the styling to the actual text rather than underlining the `li`  Your right in the fact it should be border-bottom however i dont know how to recreate a glowing underline effect

Comment: Have now changed the css to achieve a similar result with border-bottom and box-shadow only on the bottom, however it does still apply the styling to the TEXT not the bottom of the `li`

Comment: sorry, my mistake, of course you should apply new class to `$(this).parent('li').addClass('active')`. I'll edit it right now.

Comment: also, I have to mention, (1) that you don't need ids both for `<li>` and `<a>` to do that, (2) you can use it only for `<li>` (in this case you don't need `.parent('li')` inside script) and with `cursor: pointer;` style for '<li>' it looks better imho: http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/sJNMR/2/

Comment: Have altered code to your advice, however it still doesn't underline the `li`, it also only underlines the text on "3D"

Comment: and change `link` to `links` on line where you remove class

Comment: It sound stays underlined! However it doesn't change the border-bottom colour to the purple sort of colour it should be. Also, is there any reason why 3D might still be underlined?

Comment: Have changed the id of the 3D `a` and the corresponding id's within the JS and it all works as it should now.
However, the original border-bottom shows through instead of changing colour?

Comment: try to change position of `.active` (line 91) and `#portfolioNav li` (line 177) because it seems to override the property, I meen put it lower in your css file

Comment: or simply delete botom-border style from `#portfolioNav li` (line 180) because it duplicates line 65 and, as I say before, overrides your `.active`

Comment: SPOT ON! Thankyou SO much for all your help. If i could upvote this a thousand times I would!